# Input string was not in a correct format.Couldn't store <9.99999999748979E-05> in diff Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am running a long sequence of SQL code (RESQL actually). And it fails at a certain update statement in it.
The log says -
Input string was not in a correct format.Couldn't store <9.99999999748979E-05> in diff Column.

```
0.000 Execute: update total
  set diff = 9.99999999748979E-05, review = 'CORRECT'
  where dim_value = 'AWD-552360'
0.479 Input string was not in a correct format.
```

Here Diff, is a REAL datatype and whenever its getting the value (9.99999999748979E-05), its failing.

Can someone please suggest a solution?

Comment: Are you sure? data type of diff column in real. Please check. real data type column can accommodate 9.99999999748979E-05.

Comment: [I can't reproduce this...](https://rextester.com/RXC97729)

Comment: yes it is Real..  (.declare diff       real 0 ). I did a check again. Its failing while calculating (420.4101 - 420.41)

Comment: I don't think `Input string was not in a correct format` is an SQL Server error, so it's coming from somewhere else. No idea what this "resql" is, but I think you need to look into it.